# Visual Studios 2015 Debuging - Step Over recursive function too slow

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, debugging, slowdown

I just recently upgraded to VS 2015 from VS 2013. I exported all my settings from VS 2013 to VS 2015.

I was just learning/testing the new Diagnostics tool and Debugging features when I encountered this in debug mode :

[image: Debugging Too slow =50%]

I stepped over the `int l = fib(n-1);` and the debugger said it too  about 121 ms but in reality I actually waited for more than 2 seconds and its unnaturally slow.

But instead if I just step over the whole function I have no problem and it takes less than 2ms and no actual delay.

[image]

I think this has something to do with the new Diagnostics tool, but I don't know how to fix this. I did some research and found out that conditional breakpoints may cause this issue as the debugger has to stop check the condition and then resume normal execution. Bu I have no conditional breakpoints just a normal one.

How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: Mayhap it is implementing step as a conditional breakpoint, with the stack pointer being the condition, and the recursion is churning it?

Comment: I think so too. The question is how do I avoid that while stepping over ?

Comment: Can you try debugging without the Diagnostic Tool attached?